# Changing colour of the close button in Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, colors

I'd like to change the colour of the red close button in the top right of each window (Windows 8 / 8.1). Presumably there's an RGB code / hex code somewhere in the registry that I could edit?

Comment: no you can't change this in the registry. You need to edit the Theme file.

Comment: Thanks for the response. What's the folder and filename of this file?

Comment: the files have the extension msstyles and are located in **C:\Windows\Resources\Themes**